# Correct way to populate an array from a promise

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm entirely new to modern JavaScript. I'm trying to populate an array with data I get from a promise from a helperService.

```
export class PeopleTableComponent implements OnInit {
    people: Array < Person > = [];

    constructor(public helperService: HelperService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void { 
        this.helperService.getPeople().then(res => {
            res["people"].forEach(function(person) {
                let person = new Person();
                person.name = person.name;
                this.people.push(person);
            });
        });
    }
}

class Person {
    name: string;
}
```

However `this.people.push(person);` doesn't work since `this` is `undefined` (as I verified in debugging).

In other frameworks, I used to solve this with `.bind(this)`. Maybe this would work here but is it the correct way? What is the recommended way to pass the context inside the promise callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrow functions would fix that.

Plus you don't really need to instantiate a new `Person` Object, every single time. In Angular, we generally use interfaces for static type checking. So unless you have a very strong reason to use `class`es instead, just use `interface`s.

Keeping all that in mind your code can be refactored to:

```
export class PeopleTableComponent implements OnInit {
  people: Array < Person > = [];

  constructor(public helperService: HelperService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.helperService.getPeople().then(res => this.people = res.people);
  }
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
}
```

Comment: Precisely the kind of modern best-practice guide I've needed, thank you! The automatic creation of the array of Person instances in just one line is insane!